# How can I run this REST API call from PHP?

Tags: php, rest, curl, parse-platform

I'm currently building a project based on the Parse.com backend that includes uploading files.
Users can upload files and then access a list of these/download them, this all works fine.
However, I'm not sure how to implement the command to delete an upload. [From the Parse.com forums](https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-delete-a-file) as well as the [Parse support document](https://parse.com/docs/rest#files-deleting), the call is:

```
curl -X DELETE \
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: <YOUR_APPLICATION_ID>" \
    -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: <YOUR_MASTER_KEY>" \
    https://api.parse.com/1/files/<FILE_NAME>
```

I've had a bit of a look online but the only curl commands I can find to execute commands is curl_setopt. I imagine the above needs to be converted, can anybody help with this or point me in the right direction?

So basically I need to be able to press a button on a website (through PHP) and have it run the above command.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use PHP's cURL library to do this.  If you are interested, I have actually implemented a lightweight REST client class based on cURL. You are free to use it.  Here is the link: https://github.com/mikecbrant/php-rest-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to given info you have to set custom request method `'DELETE'` (by `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` option) as well as custom headers (by `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option).

So the code should look like this:

```
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'DELETE',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'X-Parse-Application-Id: <YOUR_APPLICATION_ID>',
        'X-Parse-Master-Key: <YOUR_MASTER_KEY',
    ),
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/<FILE_NAME>',
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you very much for the response. I'll try it out in a bit. For now I was looking at AJAX, and have the following code, but when I run it nothing happens. Is this do you think an acceptable way of doing of or will I need to do it in PHP?

http://pastie.org/private/tcse5mfx4yodcptelznbw

Comment: then probably your account is not okay... try it out with a rest client addon first

Comment: @theuseduser I'm not familiar with `parse.com` API. I just gave answer to your question in CURL terms.

Comment: after much playing around, I've finally managed to get it to work, thank you very much hindmost!!

Answer (score 1):

If it's useful I made a simple class to handle the api calls request via Curl

https://github.com/niklongstone/php-api